# Xcode 4 - selecting / deselecting multiple targets on file import

Tags: xcode, file, import, target

I have a project with over 30 targets (customized versions of a similar code base).  In Xcode 3.x when adding a file to the project to support a specific target, the target selection list had 2 convenient right-click choices - select all and deselect all.  This feature seems to be missing in Xcode 4.  Not only that, but the target list is now only about 4-5 rows high, forcing a lot of scrolling.

The other approach - importing the file to all targets (the default) and then deselecting all but one on the right info menu is painfully slow.

Am I missing something?  Is there another way to import a file for a specific target?